# JQuery - assigning method to a variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I was creating a new web page based on the code another developer has written. However there is one part of the code that is really confusing me and I could not find any helpful answers/tips.

So what I am trying to accomplish is to dynamically add rows to a table. The original code is below:

```
$('#botton').on('click',function(){
    var table = $('#table') ;
    var tr = table.find('tr').first().clone().appendTo(table);

    tr.find('select').selectpicker('val', '');
    tr.find('input').val('');
});
```

The confusing point for me is how the `var tr` works. The way I understand the code is: it first gets the current table, then clone the first row and append it to the current table. And then find the row and clean up all previous inputs.

However, since we use `appendTo(table)` before the cleanup, how can these two codes 
`tr.find('select').selectpicker('val', '');
 tr.find('input').val('');`

still have effects on what is appending into the table?

I did some testing and changed the code like this

```
$('#botton').on('click',function(){
    var table = $('#table') ;
    var tr = table.find('tr').first().clone();

    tr.appendTo(table); 

    tr.find('select').selectpicker('val', '');
    tr.find('input').val('');
});
```

This code seems the same to me but

`tr.find('select').selectpicker('val', '');
 tr.find('input').val('');`

won't have effects on what it appends to the table anymore.

This is my first post so I apologize if I make any editing mistakes. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Are you saying the two pieces of code work differently or the same? It seems they both do exactly the same thing

Comment: No they work differently and that is why I feel confused. They look the same to me too. On the second one all the modification after tr.appendTo(table); won't affect what is inserted into the table.

Comment: looks the same to me though

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `appendTo()` is the jQuery object that's being appended, i.e.

```
el1 = el2.appendTo(table);
```

is equivalent to:

```
el2.appendTo(table);
el1 = el2;
```

So the code you posted sets `tr` to the result of `clone()`, i.e. the new row that was added. Then the following `tr.find()` calls search in that row.

The general rule in jQuery, like most fluent interfaces, is that methods return the object they were called on if they don't have a more specific value to return, to allow for object chaining. So all these `obj.method()`
calls return `obj`. This is why there's both `append()` and `appendTo()`: `container.append(child)` returns `container`, `child.appendTo(container)` returns `child`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I still feel confused though... So here var tr = table.find('tr').first().clone().appendTo(table); I think the value of table.find('tr').first().clone() has been appended to the table. Why the tr.find('input').val(''); will still affect the table??

Comment: `tr` is the value of `table.find('tr').first().clone()`. It was appended to the table. So `tr.find("input")` is in the table.